# SQL statement from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to run a sql statement to pull data from 2 tables I was wondering if someone could help me with my code. I would like to pull `Project.Project_ID`, `Project.StartDate`, `Project.Users` where `Project_ID = 1` in both tables.

[image: dbo.Project]

[image: dbo.UserList]

```
SELECT Project.Project_ID, Project.StartDate, Project.Users
FROM Project
INNER JOIN UserList ON Project.Project_ID=UserList.Project_ID
WHERE Project.Project_ID = '1';
```

Comment: Below dbo.UserList is the code I have so far

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please note that images are not considered good; please post your table structure as formatted text. Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: I think you got it.  I mean you have the correct sql statement.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the statement you have? Are you getting an error? The wrong results?

Comment: When you say you want data from both tables, do you perhaps mean you want all of the data from both. Consider using `union all` if that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what is your problem statement. If you can provide more details (DB Structure) that would be really helpful.

There could be more that one scenario you want to solve based on your data structure.

The only thing I see here is instead of `Project.Users` you should have `UserList. Users`. I assume User list tables having all the users details and it's not a pivot table. If it is then you need another join with User table.

```
SELECT 
       Project.Project_ID, Project.StartDate, UserList.Users 
FROM 
       Project
       INNER JOIN UserList ON Project.Project_ID=UserList.Project_ID
WHERE 
        Project.Project_ID = '1';
```

Please share your Database Structure.

Answer (score 0):

With your model a user can only be linked to one project.
Below is with an joining table UserProject.
This way n users can take part to n projects. (n to n relation)

```
SELECT
    p.id AS projectId,
    p.startDate,
    u.id AS userId,
    u.name,
    [...]
FROM
    Project AS p,
    UserProject AS up,
    User AS u
WHERE
    p.id = up.projectId
    AND u.id = up.userId
    AND p.id = 1;
```

And here is with a 1 to 1 relation

```
    [...]
FROM
    Project AS p,
    User AS u
WHERE
    p.id = u.projectId
    AND p.id = 1;
```